# How to create a persistent USB key of a running system?

Tags: usb, system-installation, system-recovery

How to create a persistent and bootable USB of a running system on a computer without shut down.

The key would be the same as the computer and offer ways to use it and install it as is on some other hardware.

. root rights ok

quote from chat Unix & Linux

> To keep the things simple, I would like to create an alive backup ...
>   example
>   you run on your machine
>   you have to leave ... you plug the key
>   you load the command
>   and then you plug the key on another place and have everything working like at home
>   so not just a backup
>   not just a live usb
>   but a persitent of your system as is.

Comment: what do you mean by "running system" - unable to shut it down during the process?!

Comment: precision added @jet

Comment: Maybe a tool like remastersys (or respin) may fullfill your needs – although I have to admit not knowing if these do only ISO images of your system and what you will have to do additionally to get it as bootable USB stick.

Comment: @Jaleks as explain in the bounty, I look for a one shot command line or bash script solution

Comment: sorry for not delivering the cake, but just the possible receipt for bakers…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dd is the good way to proceed.

Meanwhile, this solution works out of the box only if there is only one /dev/sd*.

For instance, i would suggest to list all /dev/sd* except usb one then make as many partition (fdisk -n) as required on usb drive and use dd for each /dev/sd* counted.

From the link:

```
insert the destination USB flash drive in my workstation
delete the existing vfat partition and create a single linux partition using fdisk
create a filesystem and synchronize it:

bash# mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
bash# sync ; sync

remove the usb flash drive from the workstation, put it in the target PC
mount the usb drive, move the udev filesystem out of the way, and copy the local filesystem:

bash# cd /
bash# mkdir /mnt/sda1
bash# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
bash# mkdir udev
bash# mount --move /dev /udev
bash# cp -ax / /mnt/sda1

That copy command might take awhile. When it is done, get rid of the temporary directory /udev

bash# mount --move /udev /dev
bash# rm -fr /udev
```

Now to make the usb drive bootable. It should still be mounted at /mnt/sda1. First, in file /mnt/sda1/boot/grub/device.map set hd(0) to /dev/sda and in /mnt/sda1/boot/grub/menu.lst set the kernel boot options correctly for each boot configuration, eg:

title           Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 2.6.18-6-486
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-6-486 root=/dev/sda1 ro vga=792 
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.18-6-486
savedefault

Finally, install grub on the usb flash drive:

bash# grub-install --root-director=/mnt/sda1 /dev/sda

All done! Now you can reboot into the flash drive.

Comment: Could you be more explicit .. like a one shot command line or a bash script?

Comment: bash script called in a one shot command :)

Comment: Somebody seems to had already fix this previously :)
http://radagast.ca/linux/copy_hd_to_usb.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the same set of partitions on the USB stick (cfdisk). Identification of disks / partitions is easy with `cfdisk` and `cat /proc/partitions`
2. Format them with the same file systems (mkfs.ext....)
3. Mount them (i.e mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/sdXY)
4. Copy the files for each partition to the corresponding partitions (ie `cp -a /bin /boot /dev /etc /home /mnt /root /sbin /usr /var /mnt/new`)
5. `cd /new
   mkdir proc
   chmod 555 proc
   mkdir tmp
   chmod 777 tmp`
6. Edit fstab in USB accordingly
7. Install Grub on USB stick
   `mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/  #if is not mounted already
   mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
   mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   chroot /mnt/ /bin/bash
   /usr/sbin/grub-install --recheck --no-floppy /dev/sdXY`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a USB hard drive that is at least as large as your computer's disk. Not just the size in use, total size.

You'll need to identify which devices in `/dev/` are for your main HD and for your USB. *Usually* `/dev/sda` will be your main disk, and `/dev/sdb` will be your first peripheral.

---

You can use `dd` on a live filesystem, though there are risks associated with that ([Using dd to clone a disk while mounted - risks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244983/using-dd-to-clone-a-disk-while-mounted-risks)). Alternatively, you can use `cat`, which might be safer ([When is dd suitable for copying data? (or, when are read() and write() partial)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial)).

Assuming your main device is `/dev/sda` and your USB device is `/dev/sdb` you can use either of the following:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=64k conv=noerror,sync

cat </dev/sda >/dev/sdb
```

`dd`'s `noerror` causes it to continue on errors, and its `sync` fills partial writes with zeros so things don't get shifted out of place. Though both of these things may be reasons you'd want the `dd` to stop, as they indicate problems with the image `dd` is creating.

---

If you want to install the USB image onto another hard disk, you can boot into it and run the same commands. It will be important to identify which is the USB drive and which the internal HD in that case, not sure if it will treat the drive it's booting from as `sda`.

Comment: This response sounds great, I have to test before give the bounty points.