# Command to DD Write Only if Different?

Tags: backup, dd, disk-image

I usually keep image based backups of certain computer drives that I generally create with a dd command piped into gzip (or similar).  To restore a backup I simply reverse the process.  Works great for spinning drives, however, with SSDs I hate wasting writes to restore data that is already present on the drive.  I might write 1TB to an SSD and shorten it's life by a percent or two when technically only a few gigabytes of data differed between what's already on the drive and what's in the image backup.

So I was wondering, is there a way to restore a dd image but only write data to the drive if the data differs?  It doesn't have to be a byte by byte check, even if it compares blocks of data and then writes that block only if any data in that block differed that would be very helpful.

Comment: Somewhat related: [*In-place delta writes from a pipe*](https://superuser.com/q/1358525/432690).

Comment: Related - [Using dd to clone a disk while mounted - risks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244983/100397) and possibly [How reliable is a system backup created with the dd command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/628376/100397)

Comment: Could use the answer mentioned here: https://serverfault.com/a/969077/135542

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a faster alternative.

My current best effort on this is:

```
xdelta3 -e -s /dev/mmcblk0 <(zcat backup.img.gz) /tmp/delta
xdelta3 -d -s /dev/mmcblk0 /tmp/delta /dev/mmcblk0
```

This ends up being quite slow, but seems to avoid the write-amplication effect.

Since the bot noticed this answer - `xdelta3` has been available in Debian distributions for a while now (`apt-get install xdelta3`)

> Xdelta3 is a set of tools designed to compute changes between binary files. These changes (delta files) are similar to the output of the "diff" program, in that they may be used to store and transmit only the changes between files. The "delta files" that Xdelta3 manages are stored in RFC3284 (VCDIFF) format.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, since the majority of users will likely be unfamiliar with the `xdelta` tool, you may want to add some explanation on what it does and where it is available.